# What are supported ffmpeg rtp_mpegts Muxer options? (mpegts Muxer options are ignored)

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtp, dvb, muxer

I created a UDP stream with `-f mpegts` and some options like `-mpegts_transport_stream_id`.

I received the stream with "*StreamXpert - Real-time stream analyzer*" that shows all options are in the output. See my ffmpeg parameters and the StreamXpert at the end.

The same Muxer options seem to be **ignored** with `-f rtp_mpegts`.

I have tried to use `-f mpegts` and pipe it to `-f rtp_mpegts` like so:

`ffmpeg -i ... -f mpegts pipe: | ffmpeg pipe: -c copy -f rtp_mpegts "rtp://239.1.1.9:1234?pkt_size=1316"`

The options are still **ignored**.

This ticket "[support options for MPEGTS muxer when using RTP_MPEGTS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5239)" also notices the ignored option. Furthermore in this [comment](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5239#comment:4), "*thovo*" gives an analysis and suggests a solution.

Obviously the problem still exists. Anybody found a workaround for this?

My additional question: I have not questioned if my project really needs rtp in the first place. Maybe my coworker didn't know better and requested rtp when udp would be sufficient as well.

The aim was to receive the RTP stream with a TV using DVB via IP. This was successful an a Panasonic TV.

The [SAT>IP Specification](http://www.satip.info/sites/satip/files/resource/satip_specification_version_1_2_2.pdf) on page 10 requires rtp for Media Transport:

The SAT>IP protocol makes use of:

- UPnP for Addressing, Discovery and Description,
- RTSP or HTTP for Control,
- **RTP** or HTTP for Media Transport.

Is udp out of the equation?

---

ffmpeg: (all options are in the output with `-f mpegts`)

(HEX to decimal: `0x005A` = `90`, `0x005B` = `91` `0x005C` = `92`, `0x005D` = `93`, `0x005E`= `94`)

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc \
-r 25 \
-c:v libx264 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-profile:v main -level 3.1 \
-preset veryfast \
-vf scale=1280:720,setdar=dar=16/9 \
-an \
-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb \
-flush_packets 0 \
-b:v 4M \
-muxrate 8M \
-pcr_period 20 \
-pat_period 0.10 \
-sdt_period 0.25 \
-metadata:s:a:0 language=nya \
-mpegts_flags +pat_pmt_at_frames \
-mpegts_transport_stream_id 0x005A \
-mpegts_original_network_id 0x005B \
-mpegts_service_id 0x005C \
-mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0x005D \
-mpegts_start_pid 0x005E \
-mpegts_service_type advanced_codec_digital_hdtv \
-metadata service_provider='WI' \ 
-metadata service_name='W' \
-mpegts_flags system_b -flush_packets 0 \
-f mpegts "udp://239.1.1.10:1234?pkt_size=1316"
```

*StreamXpert* Output:

`-mpegts_transport_stream_id` = `Transport Stream ID` (yellow text highlight)

`-mpegts_original_network_id` = `Original Network ID`, `onw` (green text highlight)

`-mpegts_service_id` = `Program`, `service` (pink text highlight)

`-mpegts_pmt_start_pid` = `PMT PID`, `Table PID` (turquoise text highlight)

`-mpegts_start_pid` = `PID`, `PCR PID` (red text highlight)

`-mpegts_service_type` = `service type` (blue text)

`service_name` = `Service name` (orange text)

`service_provider` = `Service provider` (pink text)

[image]

Comment: I'll send a patch for this in a week or two.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: @Gyan, if you need any help with testing or access to a "StreamExpert" instance, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the mpeg TS option summary. Very useful.

Comment: @Gyan did you ever get the patch out for this? Hoping it will preserve PIDs set via the -streamid option as the rtp_mpegts muxer doesn't seem to do this at present

Comment: The feature will be included in ffmpeg `release 4.4`